# Winrar batch process to compress folders from a list.txt causing error with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, winrar

I made the following batch process to compress multiple folders in a `list.txt` file.

```
call "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR" a -Rar -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep3 C:\Backup\Backup.rar @list.txt
```

This works perfectly when I run it. But when I schedule this batch file to run using Windows Task Scheduler it gives an WINRAR error:

> Cannot open list.txt The system cannot find the file specified.

The task was simple Start a program => "C:\Batch\backup.bat"

A solution I found here was to start this from Command Line like:
`cmd /c "C:\Batch Backup\backup.bat"` <= also tried this but it gives the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `@"c:\some\where\list.txt"`?

Comment: omg.....I cant believe that was the issue. Thnx alot MC ND it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeat the right answer given by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) in a comment to get this question removed from list on answered questions.

The first mistake in command line

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR" a -Rar -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep3 C:\Backup\Backup.rar @list.txt
```

was not specifying the list file with complete path resulting in list file not found in current working directory on execution as scheduled job.

A second small mistake is `-Rar` on command line as this has no meaning. The switch to force creation of a RAR archive is `-afrar`

So the correct command line is:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afrar -m5 -ed -pTest -r -ep3 C:\Backup\Backup.rar "@Full Path To\File\list.txt"
```

Better would be for a scheduled batch job to use console version of **WinRAR**:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -m5 -ed -inul -pTest -r -ep3 -y C:\Backup\Backup.rar "@Full Path To\File\list.txt"
```

There is no need for `-afrar` as the console version `Rar.exe` supports only RAR archive format.

The switches are explained in text file **Rar.txt** stored in the program files directory of **WinRAR**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unix-like (Linux, OS X, etc.) system, you can can even generate the list file on the run:
`rar a [whatever -switches you use] output.rar @<(find /where/to/find -type f -name 'wildcard_pattern')`

This will find all the files in a specific path that match your given wildcard pattern, add all found paths to a temporary file (technically pipe to a fifo file), then pass it to rar command, after the compression complete, the list will be removed automatically.